# How to import a page break from html to google docs?

Tags: google-docs, google-docs-api

I'm trying to export a document in html and import it again (for the purpose of the test I don't even edit the file). After exporting, I can see that the page break is kept in the html :

```
<hr style="page-break-before:always;display:none;">
```

But after I import this file into google docs, and do the conversion, the page break is not materialized in the document. I can only see a line where the pagebreak should be.
Is there is a way to make it working ?

PS: I'm using the python gdata v3 API.

Comment: Yeah, I did a little bit of programming on the Gdocs API, and it looks like their import export capabilities are for getting things mostly correct between operations. I don't think that they mean for you to be able to get everything correct in every format, or this would not be a problem...

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by "the page break is kept in the html."  Last time I checked, HTML didn't know what a page break was.  Do you mean line break?

Comment: @DavidGorsline html does not, but CSS does : http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/page.html#page-break-props

Comment: Thank you!  I have learned my new thing for the day!

Comment: hello @Jeremi, were you able to produce the google document with page breaks ?? i'm having the same problem, thanks!

Comment: @Jeremi Any luck with this? Having the exact same requirement...otherwise have to pay for phpdocx...urgh.

Answer (score 6):

I've also been looking for this. It seems this is as easy as adding:

```
<hr class="pb">
```

Credit: https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/docs/fqLmAJkPpTs