# convert HTML into Google Docs

Tags: html, google-drive-api, google-docs

I'm working with the Google Drive SDK and trying to convert an HTML file to Google Docs. It works, but the HTML/CSS support seems quite poor - which surprises me - and there seems to be little to no documentation on what HTML or CSS is actually supported.

It seems it doesn't support block elements like divs and page breaks with `page-break-after` for example are impossible?

If anyone has any experience or tricks to make Google Docs interpret HTML better - especially page breaks...that would be much appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Can I ask how do you convert HTML file to Google Docs? I looked through the documentation (https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/integrate-open#open_and_convert_google_docs_in_your_app) but only found ways to export Google Doc to HTML. Thanks!

Comment: Did you ever figure out a solution to this?

Comment: you can do it with drive.files.create() then drive.files.update() and when you update, pass in  const media = {
    mimeType: 'application/vnd.google-apps.document',
    body: YOURHTML,
  };

Answer (score 0):

I think HTML can't do the trick but you can do it in CSS. Specifically, they are **`page-break-before`**, **`page-break-after`**, **`page-break-inside`**. Here is a [documentation](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/page.html#page-break-props) that you can refer with. At the same time, this [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10418357/how-to-import-a-page-break-from-html-to-google-docs) also mentioned about this topic.

Comment: Thank you - I should have mentioned HTML/CSS in my original question. I have of course tried that CSS, but it doesn't work. Thanks for the reply though.